# How to access authenticated user in other than Authentication Controller in Grails?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.2

I am using `Authentication 2.0.1` spring security plugin to authenticate my web services . I am in success to login and set user session through Authentication Service . I also get `sessionUser`and `isLoggedIn` in success response in Authentication controller. But same thing I am not able to access from other controller.Please have a look into my code , I am not able to access authentication service in other than authentication controller , Please help.Thank in advance.

```
class ModuleController {

       def authenticationService
       def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&auth]

       private auth() { 

             println 'checking authentication in module controller : '+authenticationService.isLoggedIn(request)        
       }
}
```

Comment: just now I check I got a new session in each controller, that why I didn't get my session user in other controller. but still i don't know why should new session is creating in other controller request ? please help..

Comment: can you post here, code from other controller. It will be easy to debug then

Comment: I have posted my other controller (module controller) already..please check..I got authenticationService.isLoggedIn(request) 'true' in Authentication controller but same in Module controller got 'false'.I have debugged request for both of controller..I recognize the different session for Module controller..That's why I didn't get isLoggedIn 'true' in new session for Module controller..now I have to find why should session get changed in Module controller ?